# How to log values that Hibernate binds to prepared statements?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, logging, prepared-statement

How can I make Hibernate log the values it binds to prepared statements?

If I set property `hibernate.show_sql=true` I get following kind of logging:

```
insert into tablename (field1, field2) values (?, ?)
```

I'd like also to know what values are bound to question marks.

I am using Hibernate 3.2.7.ga.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to set the following  logging category to `TRACE`

```
org.hibernate.type
```

And personally, I don't use the `show_sql` property, I work with `DEBUG` enabled for the category:

```
org.hibernate.SQL
```

This way, I have a single place to configure everything.

#### Reference

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [3.5. Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)